# How can I create an animated tap bar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-menu

I have an iOS app and I included this library from this link [GitHub](https://github.com/softhausHQ/CircleBar). I'm going to develop the same app for Android Studio, but where do I start or where to get something like this?

[image]

Comment: stack overflow can't help for recommendations to libraries. further than that, you've now discovered that making apps for more than one platform requires some further thinking, right ? can't make use of something very custom on one framework if the other might not support it.

Comment: Yes I undress that, and thank you for that, the problem is the client 

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Flutter then check out this library: https://github.com/JohannesMilke/curved_bottom_navigation_bar

And for Android Studio here is another library written in Kotlin: https://github.com/hamzaahmedkhan/KBottomNavigation